# Java - Read xls as text without point value

Tags: java, excel

I'm reading the xls file as per below:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
HSSFRow rowTPNB;
HSSFCell cellTPNB;
rowTPNB = sheet.getRow(5);
cellTPNB = rowTPNB.getCell(1);
```

With that code i'm getting the value from excel which like this `76653764` to `7.6653764E7`. How do I do to remain value to `76653764`. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

`Double.valueOf("7.6653764E7").longValue();`

This will return a `long` value and remove the scientific notation :)